Why Cayley 2-Complex for a group is simply connected?
In Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology " Section 1.3 , page 77 he defined Cayley Complexes for a group . In the second paragraph it is written that $\tilde{X_G}$ is the universal cover of $X_G$ since it is simply connected . This can be seen by considering the homomorphism $\phi:\pi_1(X_G)\to G$ . For an edge $e_\alpha$ in $X_G$ corresponding to a generator $g_\alpha$ of $G$, it is clear from the definition of $\phi $ that $\phi([e_\alpha])=g_\alpha$ so $\phi$ is an isomorphism ,in particular the kernel of $\phi$ is $\tilde{p}(\pi_1(X_G))$ , is zero , hence also $\pi_1(\tilde{X_G}) $ is zero , since $\tilde{p}$ is injective .
Here $X_G$ is the two dimensional cell complex with $\pi_1(X_G)\sim G$ , $\tilde{X_G}$ is the Cayley complex of $G$ and $\tilde {p}:\tilde{X_G}\to X_G$ is the covering map.
I have the following doubts :

Why $\tilde{p}(\pi_1(X_G))$ is the kernel of $\phi$?


We can show the above using covering space action of $G$ on $\tilde {X_G}$ . But how to show that action is a covering space action? Why it's fixed point free?

